# Apache 2.2 won't start

Tags: apache-2.2

After yum update my apache won't start, I got the following errors:
`# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_alias.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_authn_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]`

The line 13 follows:
`Header: PidFile run/httpd.pid
# MR -- must be disable here because can not overrite! -- importance for proxy-to-apache
# Listen 80
....
Line 13: LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so`

Comment: "I use Apache 2.2, php54m and PHP-FPM on CentOS 6.7" is a really bad question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you updated from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 then this makes sense. This is because mod_authn_alias doesn't exist anymore. Its functionality resides in the mod_authn_core module. Commenting out the line 13 from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Mugurel, so I should edit to remove this line 13..?

Comment: Yes, you should add `#` in front of it, save the file and try and start Apache.

Comment: I've added # but doesn't help, it always reset by sh /script/cleanup

Comment: What does sh /script/cleanup do? Can you post the script content?

Comment: There's a command for kloxo that is cleanup for affected software (cleanup process for certain settings).
I don't know exactly.. but anyhow when running cleanup, all the index.php will be overwrite by default_index.php.
OK never mind, let ignore it...<br />
Let me know how to remove full apache 2.4? Because when running # yum list httpd*; dir -l /etc/yum.repos.d > There are so many show httpd24 such as httpd24u.x86_64, httpd.x86_64, httpd24-apr.x86_64, etc... (I want to use 2.2 only, httpd24 makes some problems on my server).
Sorry for many questions.